# Haskell ghci command line. return value overwrite last prompt

Tags: haskell, ghci

I installed ghci  on Max OSX.

But everytime, the return value overwrite my last ghci prompt. 
See below.

```
Falseghci>null[1,2,3]
Luke_ghci>
```

"False" over write my last line ghci prompt. (should be Luke_ghci)

So weird. How to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: What have you got in `~/.ghci`? What's your `$TERM`?

Comment: it's  :set prompt "Luke_ghci>"

Comment: @DanielWagner Even though I delete everything in .ghci file. It still over writes "Prelude>" Strange.

Comment: @DavidDegea When you run `echo $TERM` at a shell prompt (in a terminal window but *not* in ghci), what gets printed?

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg66527.html

Comment: @DavidDegea: you're welcome. Should I put the link in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the above-linked message:

> Aha! That led me to find it: I had TERM set to 'ansi'. ghci +
>   Haskeline works find if TERM is set to any of rxvt, vt52, vt100, vt102
>   or xterm. Don't know what in terminfo Haskeline is relying on, but
>   'ansi' doesn't have it!